# Materialize Model - Content underneath is visible

Tags: materialize

I'm using Materialize to generate modals on a php website, only the data below is clearly visible.
This is based on data from a MySQL database. For each hard drive in said db, generate a card and populate with drive data.
For testing purposes I removed all php code to see if that was what was breaking it, sadly I still had normal text punch through.
Any ideas? Are there css options I can use to force the opaque settings? Or maybe an alternative altogether, I did have a look at css overlays but had the same problem.

In the code below I've removed all php. The complete website source code can be found at my repo
[here](https://bitbucket.org/grahamcjordan/) (albeit without the modal stuff as not committed to master yet)

```
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-image waves-effect waves-block waves-light">

            <!-- Drive stats on index -->
            <div class="card-content center">
                <h6>Hard Drive Canonical Name Goes Here via PHP</h6>
                <ul>
                    <li>Hard Drive Size Goes Here Via PHP</li>
                    <li>Hard Drive Temp Goes Here via PHP</li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>Last updated at database timestamp goes here via PHP</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            <div class="container center">
                <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn blue darken-1 modal-trigger" href="#modal">Launch Temperature History</a>

                <div id="modal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="card graphcolour">
                            <div class="card graphcontent">
                                <canvas id=1></canvas> <!-- <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $drive['DiDriveId'] )?> is what would normally be in here -->
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        "hello there!"
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn red lighten-1">Close</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.modal').modal();
                })
            </script>
    
            <!-- Status Images -->
            <!-- Images would go here based on PHP if else statements -->
        </div>
                    
    </div>
```

The materialize modal code snippets were edited versions of below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>           
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

 </head>

<body> 
  <div class="container">
    <h3>A Demo of Modal</h3>
    <!-- Modal Trigger -->
    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn pink darken-1 modal-trigger" href="#demo-modal">Launch Modal</a>

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
     <div id="demo-modal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <h4>A Demo of Simple Modal</h4>
       <p>Content of the modal goes here. Place marketing text or other information here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn red lighten-1">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
   })
  </script>
 </body>   
</html>
```

[image: Materialize Modal error]

Comment: Hard to say without a link, but one important thing, modals shouldn't be inside a container, otherwise the container becomes the reference point. Place them before the footer.

Comment: @SeanDoherty Thanks for the clarification. I tried a whole bunch of modals yesterday and each one had the same problem. Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SeanDoherty for clarifying what I felt was the answer. I moved the Modal outside of the card, added three empty line breaks to the bottom of my card, then re-added the modal script with css offsetting. It's cheap, but it works!

```
.modalPosition{
        top: -100px;
    }
```